# Include a large amount of SubVIs in a main VI

Tags: labview

I have a large amount (about 50) of SubVIs including beyond some usage specific code a small number of GUI elements (mostly about 2: input and output).

My goal is to reuse those VIs without creating a huge mess in a new ('main') VI and collect all GUI elements on a GUI common pane a user shall finally interact with.

I tried to use the `Open VI Function`, 'VI Reference' and 'Run SubVi' like in the examples to create references for subpanels, but the subpanel ui is only shown when the program is run and the amount of additional blocks is mostly bigger than the code in the respective SubVI.
The SubVIs should be loaded only once to construct the main User Interface.

In addition: In [this](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7593/en/) tutorial they create a subVI and recreate GUI elements that are already defined in the subVI. 
I assume this behaves like passing arguments as in a text based programming languages like the snippet:

```py
def main_vi(x, y, z): # inputs x, y, z
    s = sub_vi(x, y, z) 
    return s # output s
```

Is this necessary, or can the subvi's GUI controls **directly** be reused from outside?

Is it possible to use the subVIs inside of an "main" VI that includes everything and maps everything to a common UI using tabs?

Or is it better to copy everything to the main VI, i.e. no code reuse at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking here. What is the problem you are trying to solve - is it just that your main VI's block diagram is getting too complex or are you asking about how to reuse code or to reuse front panel elements? Can you illustrate it with some screenshots and/or VI Snippets?

Comment: You might consider encapsulating each subvi's FP elements into a typedef cluster, then paste each onto the FP of your main vi. Sounds like it's going to be a mess though.

Comment: @Dave_St it's normal for the main VI of a GUI application to have a lot of controls/indicators on its diagram - I can't tell whether the asker's problem is just managing the wiring and controls/indicators (where typedef clusters are a good solution), managing the dataflow (maybe needs an event structure architecture) or encapsulating GUI functionality into subVIs (control references). I suspect the asker is a LabVIEW newbie and the answer will be simple, but without any pictures it's hard to tell.

Comment: @nekomatic I am trying to reuse code from a lot of small Vis. These also include GUI elements. I want to be able to use their functional code as well as their GUI elements on a new (the 'main') VI without creating a huge mess. Ideally it would be possible to just reference each of them and wire them up in the mainVI. I am not really able to provide screenshots, because I just have a folder with lots of VIs and now I want a new VI that uses almost all of them, rendering there GUI elements onto a single pane.

Comment: You can directly control them by getting control references. You'd need to create a utility that would register all fp control refs for every subvi on run. Then in your main vi you can reference each individual control, probably in an event structure. You won't have to rewrite any existing code but you'll now have the problem of having to manage 50 vi's worth of controls on a single panel.

Comment: It really would help to see the front panel and block diagram of at least one of your subVIs because without it I still don't really know how to advise you. I'm sure there's a straightforward answer but we need to understand the problem first.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the functionality you are going for, yo may want o look into [XControls](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3198/en/). This would allow you to encapsulate your functionality into a reusable control that could be used on a main panel without making the main panel very messy.

Answer (score 0):

Large UI's can be a pain (pun with pane not intended), especially if there are a lot of controls and indicators.  There are some useful ways to break UIs into modular components.  XControls are one of those but I don't recommend them due to their unpredictable behaviors.  Instead look into working with Sub Panels.  There is a great toolkit for this from a company called Moore Good Ideas (or MGI). [More info can be found on their website here.](https://www.mooregoodideas.com/mgi-library/panel-manager/window-panels/)

There is also a better alternative to XControls, called QControls. [More info on them can be found here.](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/QControl)

In general, though, you might want to look into a more modular framework. [More info on Frameworks can be found here.](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Application_design_and_architecture)